# Is this the right operator for min heap?

Tags: c++

i'm making an operator for dijkstra.

```
struct st{
    int node,cost;
    bool operator<(const st &p) const{
        return cost<p.cost;
    }
};
```

Is this the right one i'm looking for?

Comment: Well, does it work? it's pretty easy to just try it out.

Comment: How about you implement the algorithm first and look what operators you need on your data structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ min heap with user-defined type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2574060/3425536)